# Python: How to format a string with split function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have the following dictionary.

```
params = {'a': 'aaa', 'b': 'bbb', 'c': 'ccc', 'd': 'ddd-hoge'}
```

When printing using the following script,

```
>>> print("1: {a} 2: {b} 3: {c} 4: {d}.split('-')[0]".format(**params))
```

the output will be

```
"1: aaa 2: bbb 3: ccc 4: ddd-hoge.split('-')[0]"
```

How should I modify the script to get the same output as the following?

```
"1:aaa 2:bbb 3:ccc 4:ddd"
```

Comment: What happens when you move the closing curly brace to after `[0]`?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'split('-')'` is thrown

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
params = {'a': 'aaa', 'b': 'bbb', 'c': 'ccc', 'd': 'ddd-hoge'}

print("1: {a} 2: {b} 3: {c} 4: {d}".format(**{
    k: v.split('-')[0] for k, v in params.items()}))
```

This does the processing on the dict, and then formats for print.

#### Results:

```
1: aaa 2: bbb 3: ccc 4: ddd
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simply split afterward:

```
print("1: {a} 2: {b} 3: {c} 4: {d}".format(**params).split('-')[0])
```

Comment: It does work in this extremely limited example, but it's a terrible solution. Anything following the first dash is removed, regardless where that dash happens to be.

Answer (score 0):

An operation of that complexity won't be handled by the formatting mini language. You would have to do the transformation externally.

One way would be to make a copy of the dictionary and update the particular value you want:

```
p = params.copy()
p['d'] = params['d'].split('-')[0]
print("1: {a} 2: {b} 3: {c} 4: {d}".format(**p))
```

You could of course modify `params` in place as well. A more elegant solution might be to apply the transformation to all the values:

```
print("1: {a} 2: {b} 3: {c} 4: {d}".format(**{k: v.split('-')[0] for k, v in params.items()}))
```